# ActionScript 3 Change source of bitmap in loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a Class called RenderingImage which is a bitmap like so:

```
[Embed(source="images/thumb.png")]
var RenderingImage:Class;
```

What I am trying to do is change the bitmap image in a loop.

```
for (var i:String in homes) 
{
    var renderingImg:Bitmap = new RenderingImage();
    renderingImg.y = 50 + spaceY;
    renderingImg.x = 0 + spaceX;
    renderingImg.width = 320;
    renderingImg.height = 185;
    home.addChild(renderingImg);
}
```

Is there anyway to change the source that I put when defining the RenderingImage Class inside this loop?

Comment: Sure: **renderingImg.bitmapData = ...** whatever other bitmap data you have there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be better off not embedding your image assets in your project.  Regardless of how you store the images, you simply need to point to the new image when looping.

```
var images:Array = [
    "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeline/32/home_house_real_estate-64.png",
    "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cute-tech-icon-set-1/512/Home-64.png",
    "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/watchify-v1-0-80px/80/home-80px-64.png"
]

for (var i:int = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var house:Loader = new Loader();
    house.load(new URLRequest(images[i]));
    addChild(house)
    house.x = 65*i;
}
```

Alternatively, if you're heartset on only using explicit `Bitmap` objects, you could reference the loaded `BitmapData` after loading.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

var images:Array = [
    "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freeline/32/home_house_real_estate-64.png",
    "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cute-tech-icon-set-1/512/Home-64.png",
    "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/watchify-v1-0-80px/80/home-80px-64.png"
]
var bitmaps:Array = [];
var loadedCount:int = 0;

for (var i:int = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest(images[i]));
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
}

function loaded(e:Event):void {
    bitmaps.push(e.currentTarget.loader.content);
    loadedCount++;

    if (loadedCount == images.length) {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var houseBmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
            houseBmp.bitmapData = bitmaps[i].bitmapData;
            houseBmp.x = 65*i;
            addChild(houseBmp);
        }
    }
}
```